# Browser requests file, server downloads pdf, browser displays pdf in iframe

Tags: javascript, django, pdf, python-requests

this is what I want to do:
1) a browser initiates an ajax request to the server, asking for a pdf.
2) the server downloads the pdf, and returns the pdf for display.
3) the browser displays the downloaded pdf in a pre-existing iframe.

Below is my code. It appears to stop at the iframe part, but I suspect that its not sending the pdf properly.

Browser index.html file:

```
var uri = '/viewer/loaddrawing/';
$.getJSON(uri, {key:value}, function(data, jqXHR){
    document.getElementById("iframetitle").src = uri;               
});
```

Django server views.py file:

```
import requests
def loaddrawing(request):
    value = request.GET.get('key')
    #the key is used to generate a unique url, but for test purposes lets use the url shown below
    url = "http://cbmeturkey.com/media/109/test.pdf"
     response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
     some_data = response.read()
    return HttpResponse(some_data, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

EDIT:

I have one issue remaining: I don't want to use the below code in my index.html file anyway, because I want to actually download the pdf and use it again. The reason for this is that my index.html page uses javascript to display and hide the iframe, and with the below code the pdf is redownloaded each time the iframe is shown.

```
var uri = '/viewer/loaddrawing/';
document.getElementById('iframetitle').src = uri + '?key=' + value;
```

SOLVED:
The above issue was solved after directions from Augusto, and the following index.html code, which loads the pdf only once, although notice that now I am now modifying a div (named "divtitle") and not an iframe:

```
var uri = '/viewer/loaddrawing/' + '?key=' + value;
var htm = '\<iframe src="' + uri +'" onload="downloadComplete()">\</iframe>';
document.getElementById('divtitle').innerHTML = htm;
```

Comment: It seems like it is mixed up a litte: Do I understand it correctly: You want to make a request to the server, handing over some value. With this value a unique url is created. On requesting that url, the pdf can be retrieved. You should have two handlers on the serverside shouldn't you?

Comment: you understand correctly - the pdf is external to the server so I need to obtain it server side. Otherwise I don't understand what you mean by two handlers. At any rate see edited question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you meant was simply:

```
var uri = '/viewer/loaddrawing/';
document.getElementById('iframetitle').src = uri + '?key=' + value;
```

There is no JSON involved, so the `iframe` will get a PDF directly. However, notice that the client must have a PDF-viewer plugin, otherwise the browser will ask for a download prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much, but see edited question above. If you like I can accept this answer and make a new question for the clarified question.

Comment: The first problem seems to be in the client-side (that is, the plugin): http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/08/21/acrobat-insufficient-data-for-an-image-error-after-updating-to-10-1-4-or-9-5-2/

Comment: As for the second problem, you wouldn't solve it by making a `getJSON` call anyway, so what you need is a logic to download the file only once. (for example, not doing it onclick, but onload).